# apache error message on every system restart

Tags: windows-xp, apache-http-server, php, reboot

Every time I restart my computer, Apache "has encountered a problem and needs to close". I have Windows XP Professional SP3, and am running Apache 2.2.

Here is the screen I get when I click the "more info" button on the error dialog:

[image: Apache HTTP Server Error Screen 2]

Text:

```
Error signature
szAppName: httpd.exe                    szAppVer: 2.2.14.0
szModName: php_xdebug-2.0.2-5.2.5.dll   szModVer: 2.0.2.0
offset: 00006e21
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you look in the event logs you may find a better description of why it failed.  Does it start properly after this?

Comment: yes. it starts properly after this.